# Apply commit to multiple release branches - Git Rebase or Cherry-Pick?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am working on a project with a Master branch, of course :P and multiple release branches created over time. The version control I'm using is Git and I was looking for a way to apply bug fixes (for example) made in one release branch to the others, automatically if possible. I.e...

```
--------------------------Master
|      |        |__v3
|      |__v2
|___v1
  |____bugfix
```

If I fix a bug found in v1, and need to apply the same fix (and only the fix) in v2 and v3, is there a way I can do this conveniently in Git?

I am new to Git but thought I might be able to Chery-pick the commit and apply it, but I was wondering if the branches need to be directly related in the hierarchy? Is it possible to cherry-pick or perhaps rebase from 'bugfix' under v1 to v2 and v3? (or v3 to v2 etc) Afaik, rebase will replay all commits, so I think cherry-pick is what im looking for, but I am unsure how to achieve this. Posts I have seen cherry-pick from child to parent branch. Is what im trying to do possible?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the bugfix is a single commit, or a range of commits you can use cherry pick.

Your bugfix would be one commit and the sha is SHA1

```
git checkout v2
git cherry-pick SHA1
```

If it's several commits, find the commit sha before the first commit of the bugfix, SHA1, and the last commit sha of the bugfix SHA2

```
git checkout v2
git cherry-pick SHA1..SHA2
```

Comment: Thanks! The SHA1 can be taken from the logs, correct? Then you checkout the branch you want to apply the fix to and simply run 'cherry-pick'? Is this usually a straightforward process? Do you know of any limitations? Much appreciated!!

Comment: Also, is it generally possible to backport (later to earlier version) fixes provided code is still similar between versions?